#8 wiring to mini split keeps getting hot with only 20 Amp draw?
Okay I'm stumped here.  I just had to repair the wiring to my mini split for the second time.  The first time was last year when a fuse able link burned out at the unit.
This year the wire at the breaker got hot and melted it but didn't trip it?
Let me start at the beginning.  I'm wired straight into the pedestal for 240V, from there I've got #10 wire to the cutoff.  Coming out of the cutoff I have #12 wire into the double 20 Amp breaker, (what the mini split calls for) coming out of the breaker I have #8 wire going to the unit.
Twice now I've had the #8 wire overheat and nearly short but why?  If anything I'd think the #12 would get hot as I'm running that at 100% of it's current rating?
I don't get why this is happening?  It makes no sense to me.  Anyone have any thoughts?  I can add a drawing/diagram of how everything is wired if that will help?
Thanks in advance any help is appreciated.

Usually a loose/dirty connection.  You usually want the biggest wire at the breaker, then go to smaller wires. #8 to #10 to #12.

I'm confused.   I assume you are referring to the condenser as the "unit".   You should have wire from the breakers going to the disconnect (cutoff). Wire from the disconnect should go to the condenser.  It sounds like you have the breakers after the disconnect! And what is the pedestal?  Is that the breaker box?

As the saying goes, "a picture is worth 1000 words". Yes, please [edit] to add pics, drawings, etc.

@crip659 Loose/dirty: spot on. Larger to smaller wires? Yikes, this isn't plumbing :- ). All points in a series circuit carry the same current, regardless of gauge or resistance. See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/759502/electricity-why-is-current-same-throughout-a-circuit/759507#759507

Is any of this wiring aluminum?  Aluminum wiring itself isn't necessarily a safety issue, but requires different termination techniques to be safe, and has a reduced current carrying capacity compared to copper wiring for a given size.  So knowing if any of this is aluminum wiring will help identify potential issues.

@MTA   Larger wires first is usually a distance issue or to a sub panel issue.  It does not sound like OP has either issue, so using large wires does not make much sense.  A 20 amp draw would require 10 gauge wire with a 30 amp breaker, but again OP has not said what max breaker size for the mini is required.

I think the answer below solved it.  When I get a chance in front of the PC I'll make up a diagram of how the thing is laid out.  I tried 3 times with paint app on my phone but each time I fat fingered it and it turned into a mess.


This year the wire at the breaker got hot and melted it but didn't trip it?

NEC 110.3(B) says follow labeling and instructions. Breaker labeling specifies a torque.
NEC 110.14(D) say use a torque wrench/screwdriver to set terminal screw torques when one is specified, and was added in 2017 because people weren't paying attention to 110.3.
This is far and away the #1 reason for wire burn-up at a termination which requires a screw torque. Pro electricians are not able to set screw torques by feel.

Torque screwdrivers are not that expensive, either, if you're going to use them more than once. You may or may not find them cheaper by looking at gunsmith suppliers rather than electrical suppliers. Note: The kind that clicks free when the right torque has been reached is a lot less hassle than the ones where you have to try to read a gauge while turning.

I think you may have solved it!  I seem to remember having a bit of difficulty getting the thick wire to bend inside the waterproof enclosure and enter the breaker terminals plus have everything snap together right when I was done.  I don't specifically recall forcing it together but that is something I would do.
